# Selecting records in one table by comparing fields with a single other record

Tags: select, sqlite

I have two SQLite tables, `t1` and `t2` with identical fields: `name`, `value1`, `value2`, `value3`.

Critically, (a) table `t1` contains only a single record `John|20|19|4`, and (b) that record might change.

I would like to select from T2 all those records where t2.value1 <= t1.value1 (i.e., the single t1.value in the only record) and t2.value2 <= t1.value2 and t3.value3. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select *
from T2
where exists 
    ( select * 
      from T1 
      where T2.Value1 <= T1.Value1 and 
            T2.Value2 <= T1.Value2 and 
            T2.Value3 <= T1.Value3
     )
```

Comment: It does indeed work marvelously well. But, could you briefly explain it. It seems completely reversed from what I expected in that it appears to be selecting from T1 (which I already know exists and has the critical record) and also seems to be embedding the selection criteria in the selection from T1. As I said, completely backwards from my own thinking, but obviously correct!

Comment: The approach is to pick records from T2 as long as I can find a (the) record in T1 that fulfills the criteria. It seems a bit backwards because there is only one record for which the existence is checked.

Comment: Isn't this simpler: `select t2.* from t1 join t2 on
  t2.value1 <= t1.value1 and
  t2.value2 <= t1.value2 and
  t2.value3 <= t1.value3`

Comment: @tonypdmtr I like it; it's more concise than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. you can give it a try with below query

```
WITH (SELECT TOP(1) FROM table t1 AS record),
SELECT * FROM table t2 WHERE t2.value1 <= record.value1 AND t2.value2 <= 
record.value2 AND t3.value3 <= record.value3;
```

Comment: This looks like SQL server? The question is tagged as 'sqlite'.

Comment: Yes, the question is about SQLite. I know I tagged it as such, but I apologize for not being more explicit in the body of the question, which I have now edited. And yes, TOP is not available in SQLIte. In any case, I have not marked the answer down because the confusion was due to my own omission.